# ObjectContext instance has been disposed but I have already copied out the object

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

My code is this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public List<User> GetUsers()
    {
        List<User> Users;
        using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            var users = from u in db.Users select u;
            Users = users.ToList();
        }
        //XXX
        return Users;
    }
```

I put a breakpoint at XXX and confirmed that the object `Users` is still instantiated with actual values. I don't know what Lazy Loading actually means but some loading has certainly taken place.  But I still get this error:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used
>   for operations that require a connection.

Why is this happening?  The object `Users` is declared outside the using block, so shouldn't the garbage collector keep track that the object is still in use?

What is the way to handle this?

---

OK, I found the cause.  The User class has a Navigation property PINS.  I read that there is an Include method.  But the PINS property is not required in this particular method.  Is there an Exclude method instead?

I tried the following before the return statement, but the same error is still there.

```
        foreach (var user in Users) user.PINS = null;
```

Comment: You should use XmlIgnore or ScriptIgnore on navigation property.

Comment: I want to ignore only for this particular situation.  The `User` class when used elsewhere may need the PINS property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create DTO (Data Transfer Objects), which is a custom C# class containing only properties that you want to serialize.

```
[HttpGet]
public List<UserDTO> GetUsers()
{
    List<UserDTO> Users;
    using (Entities db = new Entities())
    {
        var users = from u in db.Users select u;
        Users = users.ToList().Select(x=> new UserDTO(x)).ToList();
    }
    //XXX
    return Users;
}

public class UserDTO{

    public UserDTO(User user){
        this.Username = user.Username;
        ...
    }

    public string Username {get;set;}
    ...
    // properties you want to serialize
    ...
}
```

Also you are implementing API little incorrectly,

I would recommend using following pattern,

```
 public class DataAPI : APIController{

     protected Entities DB { get; private set; };

     public DataAPI(){
         DB = new Entities();
     }

     // This ensures that your Context will live
     // till end of the request, so you will not
     // get dispose exception
     public override void Dispose(){
         DB.Dispose();
     }
 }
```

Also checkout Entity REST SDK, I have written REST SDK for Entity Framework, which probably does all the job including concept of Security Context which allows automatic filtering of entities and hiding properties from serialization based on the type of user that is logged on.

http://entityrestsdk.codeplex.com

Comment: Thanks. It would mean having to copy all the properties I need.